# Prevent CSS styles apply outside of angular application

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have a SPA running both angularjs and angular.  I am using kendo library for angularjs and angular. In my angular component if I set encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, it is affecting kendo css of angularjs. Any way to prevent it and apply css only to angular component

Comment: You can set the encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.shadowDom ..?

Comment: No shadowDom is causing breakage of angular animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None'** on a component will append to the `<head>` when the component is rendered. So you can take advantage on lifecycle methods ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy to add or remove the CSS conditionally in a component.

Sample snippet

```
const createElem = document.createElement('style');
createElem.textContent = "angularcss.css";

ngOnInit() {
   document.head.appendChild(createElem);
}
ngOnDestroy(){
   document.head.removeChild (createElem);
}
```